# Выполнение задачи webpack по команде

Tags: javascript, webpack

У меня в конфиге `webpack` есть два варианта обработки `sass`:

1. Работающий, тот на котором я верстаю обычно
2. Закоменченый, когда заказчик требует отдельный `css` файл

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы не приходилось заниматься редактированием конфига каждый раз, а скажем вынести это в отдельную команду, т.е. по дефолту отрабатывает первый вариант и по команде компилиться отдельный файл ?

```
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "postcss-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader"
            }]
        },
        // {
        //  test: /\.scss$/,
        //  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        //      fallback: 'style-loader',
        //      use: ['postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
        //  })
        // },
```

Comment: а почему не использовать изначально екстрактплагин? Или вы собираете стили в js файл для верстки?)

Comment: @Moonvvell ну, при верстке получается один bundle.min.js и мне ок. Вероятно, я чего то не понимаю и буду рад услышать обьяснение.

Comment: Делайте сразу отдельными файлами если заказчику нужен отдельный :) зачем игратся то в такое. Да и держать стили в js файле..ох как я не люблю изза этого вебпак. А если именно ответить на вопрос, то можно сделать два файла, один для дева, другой для продукции, и при вызове вебпака параметром указывать какой файл использовать.

Comment: @Moonvvell ок, спасибо. Но я так и не понял в чем проблема стилей в js бандле? все грузится асинхронно, гуглспид показывает 100 из 100 все счастливы, есть карты файлов стилей, редактирование все равно происходит в сасс файлах.

Comment: та не проблема) проблема в том что вам нужно заказчику отдать файл стилей а не js :) И приходится вот искать способы как это разделить \ изменить )

Comment: Да можно. Вебпак конфиг - это просто js объект, который можно генерить менять по условию. Условие можно взять из аргументов командой строки, правда работа с аргументами командной строки чуть отличается в вебпак 1 и 2. (господи, уже вебпак 3 а я еще на первом сижу...). Пример для 2го например вот: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2254#issuecomment-203528744